# R install error eurostat package on Linux

Tags: r, linux

trying to install R package `"eurostat"` on Linux mashine, but I'm getting the error output (`Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports)`) see below.

I could reproduce the same error on my other Linux machine, but could not reproduce it on Windows 7 (virtual machine).

I do not observe such behaviour with other packages (either installing new ones or reinstalling old ones works without any errors)

Any ideas on how to solve it?

```
install.packages("eurostat")
    Installing package into ‘/home/pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/eurostat_3.3.5.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4561070 bytes (4.3 MB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 4.3 MB

    * installing *source* package ‘eurostat’ ...
    ** package ‘eurostat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    ** R
    ** data
    *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    Warning: S3 methods ‘as.array.SpatialGridDataFrame’, ‘as.character.DMS’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialPoints’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialMultiPoints’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialPixels’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialGrid’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialPointsDataFrame’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialMultiPointsDataFrame’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialPixelsDataFrame’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialGridDataFrame’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialLinesDataFrame’, ‘as.data.frame.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame’, ‘as.data.frame.GridTopology’, ‘as.double.DMS’, ‘as.numeric.DMS’, ‘as.matrix.SpatialGridDataFrame’, ‘as.matrix.SpatialPixelsDataFrame’, ‘aggregate.Spatial’, ‘cbind.Spatial’, ‘cbind.SpatialGridDataFrame’, ‘contour.SpatialPixelsDataFrame’, ‘contour.SpatialGridDataFrame’, ‘dim.SpatialPointsDataFrame’, ‘dim.SpatialMultiPointsDataFrame’, ‘dim.SpatialLinesDataFrame’, ‘dim.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame’, ‘dim.SpatialPixelsDataFrame’, ‘dim.SpatialGridDataFrame’,  [... truncated]
    Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
      undefined exports: CRS, identicalCRS, getGridIndex, points2grid, bpy.colors, bubble, mapasp, point.in.polygon, spmap.to.lev, zerodist, zerodist2, remove.duplicates, degAxis, %over%, get_ll_warn, set_ll_warn, get_ll_TOL, set_ll_TOL, get_ReplCRS_warn, set_ReplCRS_warn, get_Polypath, set_Polypath, get_PolypathRule, set_PolypathRule, set_col_regions, get_col_regions, coordinatevalues, dimensions, Spatial, SpatialPoints, SpatialPointsDataFrame, SpatialMultiPoints, SpatialMultiPointsDataFrame, Line, Lines, SpatialLines, SpatialLinesDataFrame, as.SpatialLines.SLDF, LineLength, LinesLength, SpatialLinesLengths, layout.scale.bar, layout.north.arrow, sp.theme, mapLegendGrob, spplot.key, panel.ggmap, panel.gridplot, panel.polygonsplot, panel.pointsplot, panel.RgoogleMaps, sp.polygons, sp.lines, sp.text, sp.points, sp.grid, SpatialPolygonsRescale, spplot.locator, sp.panel.layout, degreeLabelsEW, degreeLabelsNS, longlat.scales, bbexpand, compassRose, as.image.SpatialGridDataFrame, image2Grid, imageScale, gridparameters, SpatialPixels, SpatialPixelsDataFrame, SpatialGrid, SpatialGridDataFrame, GridTopology, getGridTopology, areaSpatialGrid, gridlines, gridat, gridIndex2nb, getSLlinesSlot, getLinesLinesSlot, getLinesIDSlot, getSLLinesIDSlots, getSpatialLinesMidPoints, getPolygonCoordsSlot, getPolygonLabptSlot, getPolygonAreaSlot, getPolygonHoleSlot, getPolygonsPolygonsSlot, getPolygonsplotOrderSlot, getPolygonsLabptSlot, getPolygonsIDSlot, getSpPpolygonsSlot, getSpPplotOrderSlot, getSpPPolygonsLabptSlots, getSpPPolygonsIDSlots, getSpPnParts, getSpPnHoles, getSpatialPolygonsLabelPoints, select.spatial, as.SpatialPolygons.PolygonsList, dd2dms, print.DMS, char2dms, as.character.DMS, as.double.DMS, as.numeric.DMS, as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology, IDvaluesGridTopology, IDvaluesSpatialPixels, HexPoints2SpatialPolygons, flipHorizontal, flipVertical, loadMeuse, makegrid, overDF_for_rgeos, read.asciigrid, Polygon, Polygons, cbind.Spatial, rbind.SpatialPoints, rbind.SpatialPointsDataFrame, rbind.SpatialMultiPoints, rbind.SpatialMultiPointsDataFrame, rbind.SpatialPixels, rbind.SpatialPixelsDataFrame, rbind.SpatialPolygons, rbind.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, rbind.SpatialLines, rbind.SpatialLinesDataFrame, SpatialPolygons, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, spDistsN1, spDists, write.asciigrid
    ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘eurostat’
    * removing ‘/home/pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/eurostat’
    * restoring previous ‘/home/pc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/eurostat’
    Warning in install.packages :
      installation of package ‘eurostat’ had non-zero exit status
```

My R sessionInfo():

```
sessionInfo()
        R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
        Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
        Running under: Linux Mint 19.1

        Matrix products: default
        BLAS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
        LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

        locale:
         [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8   
         [6] LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C           LC_TELEPHONE=C        
        [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

        attached base packages:
        [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

        other attached packages:
         [1] gridExtra_2.3      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 lubridate_1.7.4    forcats_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_0.8.0.1      purrr_0.3.2       
         [8] readr_1.3.1        tidyr_0.8.3        tibble_2.1.1       ggplot2_3.1.1      tidyverse_1.2.1   

        loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
         [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.1     compiler_3.4.4   plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.4.4      jsonlite_1.6    
         [8] gtable_0.3.0     nlme_3.1-139     lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.4      cli_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.10 
        [15] yaml_2.2.0       haven_2.1.0      withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.4.0       generics_0.0.2   hms_0.4.2       
        [22] grid_3.4.4       tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.1       R6_2.4.0         readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.4     magrittr_1.5    
        [29] backports_1.1.4  scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.3      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1 stringi_1.4.3    lazyeval_0.2.2  
        [36] munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.2      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: Try with `install.packages("eurostat", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: Your R version is quite old too. Recommend updating to the latest `3.6.0`

Comment: @Tung Thanks, I updated R and then it worked.